# How to reuse defined web component from a micro frontend in the stitching layer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web-component, micro-frontend

I'm trying to create a demo application using micro-frontends taking the web components approach. What do I need to do so I can use the defined custom element from one micro-frontend into the stitching layer?

I've already taken the IFrame route and to use single-spa which both work but this time I'm trying to use web components with no luck.
I've also tried to add the micro-frontend to a docker container but this brought no change.

I'm defining my custom element in the micro-frontend like so:

```
class CommentSection extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}));
  }
}
window.customElements.define('comment-section', CommentSection);
```

I'm using it in the micro-frontend `index.html`:

```
<comment-section></comment-section>
```

Everything so far works. My problem comes when I'm trying to use it from the stitching layer.

From the React app, I've created a `server.js` file to pass the content:

```
server.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const htmlPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html');

  fs.readFile(htmlPath, 'utf8', (err, html) => {
    const rootElem = '<comment-section>';
    const renderedApp = renderToString(React.createElement(App, null));

    res.send(html.replace(rootElem, rootElem + renderedApp));
  });
});

server.use(express.static('build'));
```

and from the stitching layer, creating a proxy towards the micro-frontend:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

const createProxy = (path, target) => {
    app.use(path, proxy({ target, changeOrigin: true, pathRewrite: {[`^${path}`]: ''} }));
}

createProxy('/react', 'http://localhost:3000');

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('index'));
```

and importing it like so in the stitching `index.html`:

```
<head>
  <link href="/react" rel="import" async/>
</head>
<body>
  <comment-section></comment-section>
</body>
```

I'm expecting the web component to render the react component in the stitching layer as it does when I'm running the micro-frontend in isolation, but the actual result is that all the code is under the `link` html import tag and nothing is rendered under the web component tag.

web component micro-frontend
[image: web component micro-frontend]

web component stitching layer
[image: web component stitching layer]

Answer (score 1):

Your example looks overly complicated. A Web Component consists of two parts: the custom element and the script where it's defined.

So to render the Web Component you simply have to add the script to your target html, `<script src="/static/js/xxx.js"></script>` in your case, that's all. No Docker, Proxy etc. required.

In other words: you should use the Web Component wherever you put it exactly the same way like in your "micro-frontend" index.html file.

And about that `<link ref="import">`: HTML imports are deprecated (Chrome: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5144752345317376 Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/HTML_Imports)

Comment: I understand your point and I did mention that I did find some solutions that work, but unfortunately they miss the whole point of what I'm trying to achieve.
What I'm trying to do is load the web component from a remote location, not a local js file. I've shown the difference between the working solution and my problem in the screenshots above.
I'm not sure if I made myself clear enough but hopefully I did.

Comment: it does not matter where you load javascript from. a very common use is to place javascript files on some content delivery network. load your javascript from wherever you want and use the custom element tag, it just works.

simply replace your relative src url with an absolute one, ie `<script src="https://your-server/static/js/xxx.js"></script>`